# Noise problem from neighbour

Tags: windows

I have just moved into a house with an open area in the back that is glassed in.  Something that they call a Queensland room in Australia.  A patio that has glass walls and windows.  My neighbour loves his music.  How can I reduce the noise coming from his place through glass.  Is there something that can be stuck on the glass that is see through that stops the noise from coming into our space.  I don't want to antagonise him because he sounds like he is having a great time and is a nice neighbour otherwise.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Blocking noise is difficult; as @RedGrittyBrick says, double-glazing is a good but expensive solution, but just making sure there aren't any air gaps in the glass wall may help and be a lot cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution, though perhaps not always the most practical, is to upgrade single glazing to double-glazing or upgrade double-glazing to triple-glazing.

A compromise is "secondary double glazing" which is not as effective.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately to block sound you really need thermal mass and/or disruption to the scatter/reflect the noise.  I do not believe their is any kind of film which does this.

Double/secondary glazing should make a difference, but is expensive.  Another thought might be to (a) plant some bushes/shrubs between you and the neighbour to help scatter the noise (b) putting in plush carpets and "rug type" wall hangings which will absorb rather then scatter the noise and (c) consider a white noise generator or your own music.  Our minds are a bit funny like that - they tune out rain and comparitively large regular sounds, yet you can hear a mouse running across your ceiling !   None of these are anything like a panacea though.